# Node js Joi validation to send error if string contains space at start or end

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

How to create JOI validation with Node js if string contains empty space at start or end send error

example : if input is
name = "test123" //valid
name = "test(space)" or "(space)test"  // invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below regex to validate the your cases

```
Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^([a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$', 'g'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `regex` pattern to check that string does not start or end with space.

```js
Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^[^\s][^\s]+$', 'g'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt reply but it gives false even if we have space inside string.
like for "test1 test2" it gives false but i want check for only at start and end